# Как сделать модальное окно - меньше

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.catara1_class {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: 500px;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 50px;
  max-width: 250px;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.modal_active {
  display: block;
}

.modal_content {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
  margin: 15% auto 0;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px black;
  position: relative;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
}

.modal_close {
  color: darkgray;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.modal_close:hover,
.modal_close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>мода</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleses.css" />

</head>

<body>

  <img src="catara1.jpg" class="catara1_class" id="open-modal">

  <div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal_content">
      <span class="modal_close">&times;</span>
      <img class="catara2_class" src="catara2.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="D:\workspaceVsCode\cotick\kava.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Про JS забыли ?, а вообще в классе ```modal_content``` - ```width: 50%``` или на сколько меньше там надо.

Comment: Js вроде не по стилям. А за Width - спасибо

Comment: Что-бы запустить ваш код и он работал - нужен js

Comment: dresser Вообще есть возможность как-то там через  target  на  css  и через ссылки получить модальное окно, но такое решение имеет ограниченное кол-во возможностей, так что да,  JS - это то, без чего модальным окнам не жить!